# Cognito User AWS forget password step error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm doing my user management with Cognito from the Amazon WebService on AngularJS.

I have an error for the forget-password step.

I have seen how to do on the exemple given in the AWS git (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js)

But I always have this message on my console : `Error:
callListeners
    emit 
    emitEvent 
    a 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo/< 
    a/<
    emitEvent/< 
    callListeners 
    emit 
    emitEvent
    a 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo/< 
    a/< 
    emitEvent/< 
    callListeners f
    emit 
    emitEvent 
    a 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo/< 
    a/< 
    emitEvent/< 
    callListeners 
    emit 
    emitEvent 
    a 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo 
    [52]</d.prototype.runTo/< 
    a/< 
    emitEvent/< 
    callListeners 
    f 
    c/<
    finishRequest 
    handleRequest/<`

I can not figure out why its not working :

This is how I reset my user password :

```
 AuthService.forgetPassword = function(username) {
            var userData = {
                Username : username,
                Pool : userPool
            };
            cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
            cognitoUser =
                cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
                   onSuccess: function (result) {
                       console.log('call result: ' + result);
                   },
                   onFailure: function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                   },
                   inputVerificationCode() {
                     var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ' ,'');
                     var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');               
               cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
                    }
               });
            };
```

Note that the `verificationCode` and the `newPassword` getted are well setted.
Does anyone know how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look on GitHub: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/381

Though the same issue with error message format looks present here.